# R: Site Scraper Ideas

Tags: javascript, html, r

Having a tough time here. please navigate to http://www.cbioportal.org/public-portal/index.do

Towards the bottom it says: "Select from example gene sets". If you click on any one of those sets, a list of genes will appear above it. I want to scrape the genes for each of those items in the list, but the list isn't in the source HTML.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't see any R content here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The webpage actually uses JSON to pull out the data included, and you can scrape all of that easily with rjson. This code will read in all the data:

```
library(rjson)
json=fromJSON(file='http://www.cbioportal.org/public-portal/portal_meta_data.json')

user_genes = json$gene_sets[2:length(json$gene_sets)] # Remove first 'header' entry
df = data.frame(do.call(rbind,user_genes))
row.names(df) = NULL # Strip off ugly row names
```

Comment: To extract data in HTML tables, when it is not provided in a computer-friendly form such as JSON or CSV, you can also use the `readHTMLTable` function in the `XML` package.